# sass not updating changes on save

Tags: css, sass

I'm using **sass** on windows and applied `sass --watch` through cmd. it is giving css ***output*** initially, but not detecting and updating any changes that I'm making in `.scss` file.

This is what I'm doing.

I've `style.scss` in which I'm making changes and each time I've to apply

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

to convert it into `style.css`.

sass version : '**sass 3.5.1 (bleeding edge)**'
ruby version : '**ruby 2.4.2p198**'

where I'm making mistake?
[image]

Comment: Try this once `sudo gem install rb-fsevent`..

Comment: 'sudo' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Then just do it without `sudo`. I assumed that you are on mac.

Comment: @Mr_Green it get installed but problem still remains.

Comment: Can you see any error/ statement in cmd?

Comment: nope, there is no error, when I rerun the sass --watch command it says : sass is watching for changes and two more line like write style.css and write style.css.map

Comment: Maybe you are doing in another directory and checking in some other. If that is not the case, then I don't know. Try using some stable version instead of latest.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Try saving the .scss file and refresh the page on the browser and the changes will pick automatically as long as your command line interface shows this message...
`Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
      write _style.css
      write _style.css.map`

Comment: I'm using live window feature of brackets which shows changes of html,css simultaneously if I need to refresh the page, the whole motive of auto changes has no meaning.

Comment: I'm working on a webapp using Tomcat as it's servlet. So I need to restart Tomcat and refresh the page everytime changes are made to the sass code.